# Wp Login redirect strips parameters from url

Tags: wordpress, redirect, parameters, query-string, wordpress-login

**If i write** `http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://example.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat` in the url address bar (to make the login page redirect to a specific page with parameters) and login.

**I get** redirected to the right page but only with first parameter (`http://example.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog`). the other two parameters are stripped from the url.

How can i solve that?

*Btw - the parameters are acceptable on this site (set in the functions file with `add_custom_query_vars` so that's not the problem).*

Comment: why not sending params to login page like 
   http://example.com/wp-login.php?
   redirect_to=http://example.com/specificpage/
   &parameter1=dog
   &parameter2=dog
   &parameter3=cat 
then, on login page get params and construct the redirect url

Comment: Why would you do that? the redirect url is already constructed. maybe i dont really get what your suggesting...

Comment: you have 2 question marks "?" on your query string,  if you dont want to parse params and construct it again, you can use quotes to encapsulate all the redirection url like http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to="http://example.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat" so all the url with its params will be sent as one parameter

Comment: That doesn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up encoding the redirect url. using php in my case ('`http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to='.urlencode(http://example.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat));`)

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was https://github.com/Arsenal21/all-in-one-wordpress-security/issues/11
being blocked